# Eating the same meal

Tags: food-safety

Is there a meal or multiple meals I could rotate that would be safe to eat for 1 (or possibly more) meal(s) every day that would also stay good for up to a week? Ideally, this meal would be easy to prepare but all that matters is I can cook multiple at once. It seems weird but hey, batch processing is efficient and it would be super convenient if I could make about a week's worth of lunches in one night.

Comment: What is your food storage situation?

Comment: How long do you intend to repeat this process?

Comment: Kcris, welcome! Could you please clarify what you mean by “safe”? We do have a clear scope where “safe” in the sense of “contamination” and “will it make me sick short-time” is on topic, “safe” in the sense of “healthy” and “will it have an effect long-term” is not. You can always [edit] your post. I also encourage you to take the [tour] and browse our [help], especially [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: All you need nutritionally: [Soylent](https://soylent.com/products/powder-cacao-tub). No accounting for taste though...

Comment: Hello Kcris, we don't generally take questions which result in choosing a meal for you to cook. They usually have multiple answers, without one of them being objectively better than the others. This is a kind of questions which arise frequently in real life, but our site's system is ill equiped to deal with, so we close them. There is some more info on our help pages, under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things you can make in large(r) quantities that will last for a while.

pasta dishes, meat stews, rice dishes, soups...

Do them in large quantities, split them up in single servings in ziplock type bags or plastic food containers and freeze them up.

You could even do whole chicken or roasts and portion the meat into single servings

Answer (score 0):

When you search around the Internet for `meal-prep` you should find a number of recipes that satisfy your constraints. There are [whole communities](https://www.reddit.com/r/mealprep/) dedicated to it, and some popular cooking blogs also offer it as [a section or tag](https://www.budgetbytes.com/meal-prep-101-a-beginners-guide/), just to get you started.